# Restore old PostgreSQL 8.0 unicode dump to PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: postgresql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have an old backup of a PostgreSQL 8.0 database. PostgreSQL 8.0 has Unicode and plain backup options, and I used Unicode.

I tried to restore my backup using PostgreSQL 8.4 , which does not use Unicode format for backups. Rather, version 8.4  has UTF-8 backup encoding. When I restored the backup using version 8.4  it was restored, with some errors reported while restoring. But I found that some data was missing while I was checking the restore with my application.

Is there a way to restore data from  an old Unicode format backup to UTF-8 format in PostgreSQL 8.4 without data loss?

Comment: Please fix your grammar and add paragraph breaks, the details of your question are unclear.

Comment: ok sorry for that

I need to know the procedure to restore postgresql 8.0 version backup file into postgresql8.4 version

The problem is
postgresql8.0 backup was encoded in unicode format
and in 8.4 version It doesn't have the unicode format.

8.4 has utf-8 format default.

I restored the plain backup using command prompt.
but, coz of different encoding formats, the data was restored with some errors.

Can you help me on this topic?? please.

Comment: What's the *exact text of the error message(s)*? Also, is it really PostgreSQL 8.0, not something like Amazon Redshift?

Comment: error message is could not find function "headline_byname" in file D:/Program Files/Postgres/8.3/lib/tsearch2.dll

I think there is no supported .dll files in 8.3 which are available in 8.0 version

Comment: Did you try to find this error message with a search engine? Also, please find the instruction that causes this error message in your backup file. Post this instruction or the shortest possible script that reproduces the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL developers have chosen to misuse the term *Unicode* for UTF-8. Or, as you can see on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/multibyte.html, *UNICODE* is an alias for *UTF-8* in PostgreSQL.

So if all your assumptions are right, you try to restore UTF-8 as UTF-8.

I guess there is another problem anywhere.

Comment: no, in the old version they specified encoding format as unicode
if unicode and utf-8 both are same then it must be restored in postgresql8.3 or above versions without any data lose. but, here some data was gone............... and the error coming like ..............-> could not find function "headline_byname" in file D:/Program Files/Postgres/8.3/lib/tsearch2.dll
what to do??

Comment: I am still sure that there is another reason for your problem.

Comment: @HackoNee Do you think the PostgreSQL reference is wrong?

Comment: problem is previously i have windows xp and installed PostgreSQL8.0
but recently i formatted my system and Install Windows8.
Here, Windows 8 doesn't support PostgreSQL8.0 for installation.
Only Windows Xp can allow to install PostgreSQL8.0
But, I need Windows 8 for my project works, so that I format Xp and Install Windows8.

Now, the dump file of PostgreSQL8.0 is not restoring in PostgreSQL8.3 or higher version.
If you have any doubt I will send You a dump file test in PostgreSQL8.3 or higher version